# Action Event problems[C#]

Tags: c#, winforms, events

[Here](http://img706.imageshack.us/content.php?page=done&l=img706/1138/mohitapplicationui.png&via=mupload) is the UI of my application. It contains a DataSet, a Save Button, a calendar (monthCalendar), and a DataGridView (columns are Assignment, Description, Date Due, Subject Finished). I want it to do the events:

- The Calendar changes the dates to a different color if they are in the date due column
- The save button should save the DataSet as an XML file in @"\\Assignments.xml" (that is the application folder right? And not C:\Assignments.xml?)
- The row should turn a color if the assignment is finished

I'm sorry it is so much. But my application is complex and I just need these events to finish it. Whoever answers the best will be put in the README.txt file for helping me with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use a bindingsource, and bind the textbox and the description column to the same field?

For changing Calendar (datetimepicker I suppose?) date, you can add a handler for the Validated event, do a check and update the color in the handler.

To serialize the dataset to XML, you may create a class with all the fields in the data set and parse the data into the object then serialize.

Last one, not sure if you want to do this on load or dynamically or what, but I think you can add a handler for the RowValidated event, and do a check on the finished field and then set the color.

Comment: I decided to ditch the textbox idea. Thanks for the event names that helped.